# Unused/floating pins on BTS5016

Tags: integrated-circuit, pins, floating

I plan to use Infineons PROFET BTS5016 in a coming project.

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS5016-2EKA-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625a888733015aa41a5e161129

I will not use the diagnostic pins. The datasheet states that unused pins can be left "opened" or connected to GND through a 4.7k ohm resistor. I want to avoid extra components so I was planning to leave the DEN and DSEL pin floating. Also the input pins IN0 and IN1 will be floating when the microprocessor is not on (The power rails will always be on). So it would be beneficial to be able to skip pull-down resistors to save space an assembly time.

This figure from the datasheet shows the input circuitry.
[image]

Question: I cant figure out from the datasheet the exact behavior when the pins are floating, will they read high or low or be unpredictable?

Comment: If they are unused, why does it matter what they read?

Comment: That is true! Then I can float the diagnostic pins, and keep the pulldowns on the IN0 and IN1 pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Infineon tech support and got the answer some time ago.

In this application note section 10.2 it is stated that the digital pins has current sources pulling the pins low. So the pins can be left unconnected without problem!

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Application+Note-PROFET+12V-What+the+designer+should+know-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46259b0420a0159d5c957260d9c

[image]